# PHP: search in other directories if image is exist and print the image

Tags: php, image, path, directory, show

ok I edited my answer i found out how to find the file in the directories but my problem is it won't print the image. here's my code.

```
<?php
$file = 'testimage.png'; 

$dir = array(
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/folderA/", 
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/folderB/"
);

foreach($dir as $d)
    {

    if(file_exists( $d . $file )) 
    {
        $file = $file;
    } 

}

$imgPng = imageCreateFromPng($file);

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagePng($imgPng); 

?>
```

why is not printing the image?

Comment: @JohnConde I updated my question sorry for that. I've been specific now.

Comment: This confuses me, I can't even comprehend what you are trying to do/achieve

Comment: @DarylGill i'm trying to search a current image in some directories like stated above and if the image is found in the directory it gonna print it. my problem is if the image is found it won't print the image in the script.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this without adding a bunch of code would be to set up the include_path to look in the image folders, either by modifying include_path in php.ini, or modifying it in the script:

ini_set('include_path', '/new/include/path');

Then use the "use_include_path" option in fopen.

Since you're looking across all the php folders, be sure to sanity check the image file name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be because `$imgPng = imageCreateFromPng($file);` cannot find the file. You need to specify the path to your image `$d. $file`. Check the comments in code below.

```
<?php
$file = 'testimage.png';

$dir = array($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/folderA/", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/folderB/");

foreach ($dir as $d) {

    if (file_exists($d . $file)) {
        $file = $file;
        //i don't know the purpose of this but i think you want to do $file = $d . $file
    }

}

//$imgPng = imageCreateFromPng($file); //can't find the image, should be

$imgPng = imageCreateFromPng($d . $file);

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagePng($imgPng);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file = 'testimage.png'; 

$dir = [
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pathA/", 
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/pathB/"];

foreach( $dir as $d )
    {

    if( file_exists( $d . $file )) 
    {
        //set image if found in the directories
        $image = $d . $file;        
    }
    else
    {
        //is not found in directories
        $image = null;
    }   
}

$img = imagecreatefrompng($image);

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy();
?>
```